# Infinispan - Unable to specify encoding for remote cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, infinispan

I have seen quite a number of examples from [Infinispan](https://infinispan.org/docs/dev/titles/encoding/encoding.html) website and [Red hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_data_grid/8.2/html/cache_encoding_and_marshalling/marshalling_user_types) about adding encoding for the key and value of the cache, but I'm unable to do this using my current configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class InfinispanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InfinispanRemoteConfigurer infinispanRemoteConfigurer() {
        return () -> new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .clientIntelligence(ClientIntelligence.TOPOLOGY_AWARE)
                .addContextInitializers(new ProductInitializerImpl())
                .statistics().enable()
                .addServers("localhost:11222; localhost:11322")
                .connectionPool().maxActive(10).exhaustedAction(ExhaustedAction.WAIT)
                .security()
                .authentication()
                .username("user")
                .password("1")
                .realm("default")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InfinispanRemoteCacheCustomizer customizer() {
        return builder -> builder.tcpKeepAlive(true);
    }
}
```

I use the cache in a different class as below:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductCache {

    private final RemoteCacheManager cacheManager;

    public void cacheProducts(Feed feed){
        cacheManager.administration().getOrCreateCache("prodCache", DefaultTemplate.INVALIDATION_ASYNC);
        RemoteCache<String, Product> cacheProducts = cacheManager.getCache("productsCache");

        feed.getProducts()
            .getProduct()
            .forEach(product -> cacheProducts.putIfAbsent(product.getPid(), product));

        log.info("Number of Products are " + feed.getProducts().getProduct().size());
    log.info("Number of cached Products are " + cacheProducts.size());
    }
}
```

I've used and added Protostream annotations to my classes.

```
@AutoProtoSchemaBuilder(
        includeClasses = {
                Product.class, Facet.class
        },
        schemaFileName = "product.proto",
        schemaFilePath = "build/proto/",
        schemaPackageName = "products"
)
public interface ProductInitializer extends SerializationContextInitializer {
}
```

I also get this terminal warning message:

```
WARN  (blocking-thread--p3-t2) [org.infinispan.encoding.impl.StorageConfigurationManager] ISPN000599: Configuration for cache 'productsCache' does not define the encoding for keys or values. If you use operations that require data conversion or queries, you should configure the cache with a specific MediaType for keys or values.
```

I also noticed my cache only stores 1 element in regardless of how many products are in the list!
I can also see from the dashboard there's a cache miss.
I'm just not sure if these issues are in any way related.

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Update**: I finally discovered why my cache only had one piece of data! Solely because of this setting, `DefaultTemplate.INVALIDATION_ASYNC`. It evicts "stale" data when a modification is made to the cache. Found this information [here](https://infinispan.org/docs/dev/titles/configuring/configuring.html#clustered-caches).

My only issue left is to sort out the encoding which I've now seen to be different thus, now my only question as it seems I asked two questions in one!

**Update2**: the encoding is set based on the link I provided in my answer below. I only now get this error below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fighting with this for a few days, I've completely changed the way I do the configuration and removed the lambda style configuration as it was difficult to include the encoding config.
I followed this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/infinispan/clustering-infinispan-a-complete-example/) and just declared the two configuration methods as Spring beans! It sets the encoding easily now!

Answer to **Update2**:After adding these lines to the builder configuration:

```
.marshaller(new ProtoStreamMarshaller())
.addContextInitializers(new ProductInitializerImpl())
.addJavaSerialAllowList("com.person.model.*")
```

Remember to add the Proto file generated from the ProtoStream annotation processor plugin to the dashboard else, you'll get the same error message as I got in my updated question!